# How to call SQL record with PHP inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
<?php include('db.php');
```

> //it's connect the database to server

```
$sql = "select * from event";
$query = mysql_query ($sql);
?>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '2016-03-01',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
        <?php while($rs = mysql_fetch_array ($query)){
        ?>
            {
                title: '<?php echo $rs['title']?>',
                start: '<?php echo $rs['date']?>'
            },
        <?php }?>
        ]
    });
});
```

I want to show title and date as long as there is record in my database table. But this code just doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: you can't do it like that..... but this can be achieve using `jquery ajax`...

this might help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898750/is-there-a-way-to-populate-other-textbox-when-onchange

Comment: You can not mix with PHP code and javascript code.

Comment: What doesn't work? Is the data incorrect? does the query not execute?

Comment: @Roli, Sam: This *could* theoretically work just fine here.

Comment: You could use AJAX and return an array in the `response` :)

Comment: Is it your .php file? Then this should work.

But better approach will be to call server for the JSON data from your HTML page through ajax.

Comment: @JayK yup this is my .php file. But it still not working

Comment: Where is your database connection?

    $dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = 'rootpassword';
   
   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
   
   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   
   $sql = 'SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary FROM employee';
   mysql_select_db('test_db');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php include('db.php'); 

    //it's connect the database to server

$sql = "select * from event";
$query = mysql_query ($sql);
$events = array();
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array ($query)){
    $events[] = array(
        'title' => $rs['title'],
        'start' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($rs['date']))
    );
}
?>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '2016-03-01',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: <?php echo json_encode($events)?>
    });
});
```

Comment: Get rid of `$count`, you're not incrementing it anyway which leads to bugs here. `$events[] = array('title' => .., 'start' => ..);` is much saner.

Comment: i think you're not increment $count, and still it doesn't work after i tried increment it. @deceze still not working after i remove $count.

Comment: @Sairam You will have to be a bit more specific about what "not working" means! What's the generated Javascript output? Have you looked at your Javascript console for errors? Have you debugged with known good data instead of data from the database?

Comment: @chintanmirani yup it works thanks. i just know how json_encode works and the array shows `title: "title", start: "date"` until the last record.